# QGIS - Field Calculator: scale_linear gives unexpected result

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

When I try to use `scale_linear`, its output isn't as I expected. My values are from 1 to 16, so I set `domain_min = 1` and `domain_max = 16`. I want to interpolate to interval from 1 to 4 so I set `range_min = 1` and `range_max = 4`.

This is what Field Calculator returned:

`scale_linear("id", 1, 16, 1, 4)`

```
id -> scale_id
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
4 -> 2
5 -> 2
6 -> 2
7 -> 2
8 -> 2
9 -> 3
10 -> 3
11 -> 3
12 -> 3
13 -> 3
14 -> 4
15 -> 4
16 -> 4
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I'd expect `4 -> 1` and `13 -> 4`. Calculator Why doesn't `scale_linear` return 1 for values from 1 to 4 and so on?

Also, I noted that `3 / 4` is 1 (integer, precision 10). Maybe it is related with above problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already noticed, if you use your same expression for a `real` field and increase the precision, you could see that each `id` value is incremented with an almost-constant number (in your case, `0.2`) depending on the parameters you specified. These are then **rounded** to give a whole number which I assume is what your `scaled_id` field-type is:

[image: Field Calculator]

I did another simple test to confirm this using the expression `scale_linear("id", 1, 10, 1, 5)`:

[image: Field Calculator again]

Here the values get incremented by `0.444444`.

So although I get your point, I think the `scale_linear` function in the **Field Calculator** is doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I get `scale_linear` job now. The question can be reduced to _why is 3 / 4 = 1?_ I'm used to `(N - 1) / N = 0` when doing integer calculations on computer.